# ORACLE SQL Query trick. how to show one row? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Morning

I have table like this

for example

this table called "note"

```
id------alloc_code------Note_type-------Note
1        AA               ss            hello
2        AA               sc            good
3        BB               ss            something
4        BB               sc            anything
```

I would like to show

```
alloc_code     Note_Type     Note        Note_Type     Note
AA              SS           hello       SC            good
BB              SS           something   SC            Anything
```

how can I code like this?

Comment: You need to pivot, but do you have a fixed number of note-type values?

Comment: Also (in addition to Alex's question): If you have a fixed number of note types, let's say two (in your example the note types are 'ss' and 'sc'), is that the best format for your output? Why not an output with three columns, `alloc_code, note_of_type_ss, note_of_type_sc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing a `SELF JOIN` on the note table and using a `WHERE` clause  to filter note_types ss and sc:

```
SELECT 
n1.alloc_code,
'SS' AS Note_type,
n1.Note,
'SC' AS Note_type,
n2.Note
FROM note AS n1
LEFT JOIN note AS n2 ON n1.alloc_code=n2.alloc_code
WHERE n1.Note_type='ss'
AND n2.Note_type='sc';
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select alloc_code,
       'SS' as Note_Type, max(case when Note_Type = 'ss' then Note end) as ss_note,
       'SC' as Note_Type, max(case when Note_Type = 'sc' then Note end) as sc_note
from note n
group by alloc_code;
```